# Modify Twitter Bootstrap collapse plugin to keep accordions open

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to modify the Bootstrap collapse plugin to allow me to specify whether clicking an accordion (to open) should automatically close the other items in the accordion (so more than one item in the accordion can be open at a time)

I want to create a new data attribute on the accordion, something like `data-collapse-type="auto|manual"`

The bootstrap jQuery plugins are a bit advanced for my skill level. The most relevant part of what I need to mess with seems to be on line 52, `actives.collapse('hide')`. I don't want that to happen if 'data-collapse-type="manual"' is set (omitting the attribute or setting `auto` should keep the default behavior).

I've created a [jsfiddle where I've been experiementing](http://jsfiddle.net/aksKD/).

Can anyone help get me on the right track with this?

Comment: The good news is that now there is a native AngularJS directive for boostrap's accordion in http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/. Demo here: http://plnkr.co/edit/SPWkMO?p=preview

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15697970/611450):
"Just don't use data-parent attributes"!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have forked and updated your fiddle.

just go to .show function, I have written also the comments.

http://jsfiddle.net/2Rnpz/

Comment: This is prefect. Now that I see the solution, I'm certain I was overthinking it. Thanks for the quick help!

Comment: while this technically works - just be aware that modifying the core bootstrap js could lead to maintenance issues down the line, and the other answers use a declarative && supported approach to solve the problem.

Answer (score 223):

Actually, **you don't need to modify any code**. Read the following statement closely from twitterbootstrap site

> Just add data-toggle="collapse" and a data-target to element to automatically assign control of a collapsible element. The data-target attribute accepts a css selector to apply the collapse to. Be sure to add the class collapse to the collapsible element. If you'd like it to default open, add the additional class in.

So instead of using `data-parent='#idofAccordion'`, use `data-target='#idofCollapseItem'`.

It should work perfectly.

Here is the [demo on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OxbVII?p=preview)

Comment: The jsfiddle doesn't work for me: Item #1 doesn't expand at all, and I can't expand Item #2 and Item #3 at the same time. But I was able to make it work in my own app. Much nicer than hacking bootstrap.js!

Comment: Yeah, I was lazy, I only modified the first 1. Anyway, I fixed it now.

Comment: This demo appears to have dissapeared, could you reload in jsfiddle?

Comment: It is still there. You can try it again

Comment: Definitely a better answer. No modification necessary.

Comment: Surya, you're correct, all you need to do is to remove the data-parent attribute.

Comment: This works fine for me as well! +1 for making use of the attribute `data-target`

Answer (score 6):

since the question didn't refer to a specific version of Bootstrap, here's a bootstrap 4 solution:
remove the  `data-parent="#accordion"` from the  tags with the `data-toggle="collapse"` attribute. It's the example taken from the Collapse documentation with the `data-parent=#accordion"` bit taken out.

bootply:
https://www.bootply.com/3wV4WbzBtT#

Answer (score -4):

The technique for having only one accordion open at a time(that is collapse the rest), is placing both data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseOne" so it looks like this

```
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#"
    data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseOne">
  Item #1
</a>
```

You can look at it in plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/56iXtA?p=preview

Comment: This is exact opposite to what was asked !