# How to make a panel start collapsed only on phones

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In according with this example, I would like to make it start collapsed only on phones. On the tablet and desktop it should starts normally.

```
<style>
.panel-heading a:after {
    font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content:"\e114";
    float: right;
    color: grey;
}
.panel-heading a.collapsed:after {
    content:"\e080";
}
</style>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel1">
        <div class="panel-heading">
             <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" 
           href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>

        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Post Info -->
<div style='position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;    
            background:lightgray;width:100%;'>Based off this SO Question: <a href='http://stackoverflow.com/a/11658976/1366033'>Keep Bootstrap Grid Open</a>

    <br/>Based off this SO Question: <a href='http://stackoverflow.com/a/18568997/1366033'>Show Collapse state with Chevron Icon</a>

    <br/>Find documentation: <a href='http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage'>Bootstrap Collapse Usage</a>

    <br/>Fork This Skeleton Here <a href='http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/kcpma/'>Bootrsap 3.0 Skeleton</a>

    <br/>
    <div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wc4xt/1052/

Comment: first you have to detect device, see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery , then remove class 'in' to collapse collapseone. so, something like this :   `if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 $( "#collapseOne" ).removeClass( "in" );
}`

Answer (score 0):

You could have some collapse at given screen widths targeting only mobile devices (screen-md):

```
@media (min-width: @screen-md) 
{
    #targetID
    {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

The button to expand #targetID only becomes visible once the media query no longer applies.

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#targetID" class="visible-xs visible-sm collapsed">Filter</button>

<div id="targetID" class="collapse">...</div>
```