# Need a Simple Collapsible Gizmo

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is kind of weird; I've been learning jQuery and Bootstrap, and both have so many cool tools, yet I'm stumped on one of the easiest tricks in the book: a simple collapsible element.

I found the perfect candidate [here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/):

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
  <h3>I'm a header</h3>
  <p>I'm the collapsible content. By default I'm closed, but you can click the header to open me.</p>
</div>
```

The only problem is that it's jQuery MOBILE, and I'm not sure if it's a good idea to bloat my code with more JavaScript and JS. So before I implement jQuery Mobile, I'd like to ask if anyone can recommend an alternative that works with jQuery, Bootstrap, etc.

One problem is that I'm trying to make a multi-level gizmo. Clicking the initial button or heading will reveal a series of buttons like these:

```
<button id="na" class="btn btn-na"><b>North America</b></button>
<div id="div-na"></div>
<button id="sa" class="btn btn-sa"><b>South America</b></button>
<div id="div-sa"></div>
```

Clicking on North America, etc. will invoke AJAX to display a list of countries. One problem I'm having is that, when I click the North America button the "I'm a header" it's nested inside closes.

Another possibility is to reverse engineer the headers in my main content, which can be manually opened or closed...

```
<ul class="ulMain">
  <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#d1"><a href="#introduction" title="Introduction" class="NavLink">&#8226; D1 <small><span class="only-collapsed glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span><span class="only-expanded glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span></small></a></li>

  <div id="d1">D1</div>
</ul>
```

But I haven't figured out how to change the default setting from expanded to collapsed.

In summary, I'm just looking for a very simple gizmo that 1) hides content by default and 2) doesn't close after being opened until a user clicks on it again. In fact, I thought there was a way to do this with simple CSS, but I can't remember it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap collapse/accordion can hide the content by default, just omit the `in` class from the first panel in the example:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

As far as keeping the panels open until their header is selected again, without adding js, there is a great answer for that here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11658976/2460535

Short answer: Try bootstrap accordions and exclude `data-parent='#idofAccordion'`

https://jsfiddle.net/curtisweeks/jujL376j/

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to stay away from anything besides jquery, it's pretty easy on its own:

```html
<div class='collapsible'>
  <h3>I'm a header</h3>
  <p style='background:orange; display:none;'>I'm the collapsible content. By default I'm closed, but you can click the header to open me.</p>
</div>
```

Then your javascript can look like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.collapsible h3').click(function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
    })
});
```

Here's a fiddle where you can try it out:  https://jsfiddle.net/403f7k3e/